# android client not getting response from C server socket

Tags: android, c, sockets

I am able to send the string to the C server from the android client.
But I am unable get the response back from the server to the android client.
The android client is not getting the data. I want to "toast" the response got from the c server.

**Server code (c):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
char buffer[256];
char g[255];
char *message;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
int  n;
int p;

/* First call to socket() function */
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sockfd < 0) {
  perror("ERROR opening socket");
  exit(1);
}

/* Initialize socket structure */
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
portno = 5011;

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.125");
//serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

/* Now bind the host address using bind() call.*/
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
  perror("ERROR on binding");
  exit(1);
}

/* Now start listening for the clients, here process will
  * go in sleep mode and will wait for the incoming connection
*/

listen(sockfd,5);
clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

/* Accept actual connection from the client */
newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);

if (newsockfd < 0) {
  perror("ERROR on accept");
  exit(1);
}

/* If connection is established then start communicating */
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read( newsockfd,buffer,255 );

if (n < 0) {
  perror("ERROR reading from socket");
  exit(1);
}

printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

/* Write a response to the client */

//int man = 12345;
message ="hello\n";

n = write(newsockfd, message,strlen(message));


return 0;
}
```

****Android Client:****

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;


public class ScreenTwo extends Activity {
    EditText et;
String txt,ssid,key;
WifiManager wifiManager;
private Socket socket;

private Socket clientSocket;
private BufferedReader input;


static final int SERVERPORT = 5047;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.125";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();


}


 public void onClick(View v) {

    try {
         EdritText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb1);
         Sting str = et.getText().toString();
         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                 true);
         out.println(str + "\n");
         out.flush();


         BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         String read = input.readLine();
         Toast.makeText(this, read, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //ready to receive data from server
         //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         //System.out.println(in.readLine());
         //Toast.makeText(this, in.readLine(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

public void onEnterBtn(View v)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.tb1);
    txt=et.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Button disp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dispbtn);
    disp.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(txt));



} 

public void onbuttonwifi(View v)
{
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
    int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
    String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
    Toast.makeText(this, ipAddress, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 }

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         try {
             InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
             socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

         } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
         }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have a typo in your question making it unclear what works and what doesn't.  This shouldn't work in either direction because you are networking on the main thread in android.

Comment: So we have an android java client, and a C++ server, naturally we'll tag this with C (facepalm). Ironically, it does appear to be C code, so where the C++ comes in is the mystery. Btw, what is the purpose for the stand-alone `gul[200];` in your `main()` ?

Comment: ya ..my mistake...its a c server not c++ and have edited the code ...it does not have gul[200]. This code is able to connect with the c server and send a string. But the android client is not receiving the response which in this case is given by the variable "g".

Comment: `I am able to send the string to the android client from C server.`. Well if the server can send it to then the client receives it. Then what is the problem? Can you describe your scenario better please?

Comment: @greenapps ...sry typing mistake. I am able to send the string from android client to the c server. But i am not getting the response from the c server to the android client.

Comment: We cannot see what you send. Do away with that input gets and supply an example with an inbuild string.

Comment: Your code is lametably free of error checking. It isn't sufficient to just check some of the system calls. You have to check them all: `socket(), bind(), listen(), bind(), read(), write(), ...` And you also have to check `read()` for end of stream, and make use of the count returned if it's positive, rather than assuming the read filled the buffer.

Comment: `I am able to send the string to the C server from the android client.`. How do you know? Please tell what you see.

Comment: @greenapps ...Whatever I type in the EditText filed. I am able to receive it in the C server side. But the client is not getting any response back.

Comment: That's what you say. But where do you see it in your server code i asked? Further i do not believe you. As @couling already said: you cannot just send in onClick(). You should use a thread there too to send and receive.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String read = input.readLine();
```

The client tries to read a line. But the server is not sending a line with

```
n = write(newsockfd, g,p);
```

Add a `"\n"` to string variable `g` before sending. And before determining `p`.

Comment: Show your code. And with a predefined string. In your post. Not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this code will only work on very old android devices.  Modern devices do not allow networking on the main thread and you MUST move it into a separate thread.  There are enough tutorials around the web to do this.

It is generally good practice to close down sockets and files etc before simply quitting the program.  I don't believe you will fall foul of caching in the code you've written but it's always a risk so best practice says that unless you're deliberately terminating the program early (`exit(1)`) you should `close(newsockfd)`.

The most likely cause of the fault you are seeing is that `BufferedReader.readline()` expects there to be a line terminator (`\n`) at the end of every line and you are not sending one... From memory `gets()` does not include the line terminator when the user presses "enter".

On that assumption you need to do something to send the line terminator.  Either modify your string before sending or send it separately:

```
n = write(newsockfd, "\n", sizeof("\n") - 1);
```

Don't forget that you should check the response after every write as well as every read.  Writes can fail as well:

```
if (n < 0) {
  perror("ERROR writing from socket");
  exit(1);
}

// ...

close(newsockfd);
```

---

If you've tried all this and its still not working...

Look at the output of both sides make sure they are not printing any errors.  So far our responses to you have been based on the assumption that "not working" means that its hanging.  If there is an error listed on either side it would shed a lot more light on what's happening.

If it is simply hanging, then I suggest you construct a simple test client in C.  That way you can show either that it works in C only or doesn't... and therefore you can show whether the C code or android code isn't working.  You will always get more help if you can work out which technology has the problem.